# Ubuntu -> Lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, cpu-load

Not too long ago I switched from Windows 7 to Ubuntu 12.04 (64-bit) on my laptop, which only has a AMD Dual-Core E1-1200 APU 1.4 GHz processor but 4GB RAM, in the hopes that I would get more out of my weak CPU. I wonder if I could do anything further to get more out of my hardware, so I thought maybe I could switch to Xubuntu or Lubuntu. I know for example Lubuntu is much lighter on the RAM but since I have plenty of that (relatively speaking) is there a point to switching or is it a waste of time? If it is adviced for me to switch, to which version?

Also, is there a big difference in CPU intensity between 32-bit and 64-bit?

Since I am new to the world of Linux in general I'll take any advice I can get. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: This would be better asked at a site like ubuntuforums.org, where discussion is possible.

Comment: @Jeon While I agree with belacqua there is information here at AU that can help you also. http://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivate-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardware.  As it currently stands your question is more a discussion topic rather than something that be answered with a specific response.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback and I'll try to keep that in mind next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Im not really sure if the CPU is really your Problem, but its always a good idea to try some different desktop environments and look how they work out.

The main difference of the distros is the desktop environment and the main programms. Ubuntu itself may be a little bloated. XFCE and LXCE are both really lightweight but for sure very nice and useable. There are also much lighter ones like Flux/Openbox but you may dont like them for now.

My suggestion is to just try them.

You can easily install one of those desktop envs. on your current ubuntu.
http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/xubuntu

http://wiki.lxde.org/en/Ubuntu

Or just try there live CDs, with a little help of **unetbootin** you dont even have to waste actual CDs

have fun in the ubuntu world

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to reinstall Ubuntu, you can convert it to Lubuntu by running the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: Says install `lubuntu-gtk-core`, `lubuntu-gtk-desktop` before

Answer (score 1):

For using all of your 4GB RAM,you must use 64-Bit version.Normally,there isn't big difference between 32-Bit and 64-Bit.

Your cpu isn't bad for Ubuntu 12.04 and Unity Desktop.But I advice you to use AMD/ATI's drivers.To use this driver, launch "Software Sources" and then open the Additional Drivers tab.Probably,this drivers will be showed in list.Click on it and activate.

In Lubuntu,the system is used much less memory.But Unity Environment is more useful and **quickly** than LXDE.

> Also, with PAE, you can use all of your 4GB RAM on 32-Bit system.

Thanks for additional information to @jackweirdy

Comment: With PAE enabled (Which is the case in Ubuntu 12.04 onward) the system can use and access up to 64GiB of RAM.